# Talend tRestClient: how to set body in POST request

Tags: web-services, talend

How do I set body request in tRestClient similar to what I can do in tRest? I can't edit "Input Schema". It just says "body" is type Document but it's read only. I try to use a tFileInputXML with the output a document type.
But when i ru the job I had the error

```
::Exception in component tRESTClient_1 ()
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at ponant.test2_0_1.test2.tFileInputXML_1Process(test2.java:1021)
    at ponant.test2_0_1.test2.runJobInTOS(test2.java:1354)
    at ponant.test2_0_1.test2.main(test2.java:1205)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use tJavaRow before tRestClient, I keep the two columns "body|string" as in

```
String payload = "<yourxmlhere>";
output_row.string = payload;
output_row.body = payload;
```